# Can I exclude some key bindings in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 as my host system. Then I have Virtualbox with Windows 8.1 as guest OS. I am using workspaces in Ubuntu and I want to run Virtualbox in fullscreen in one workspace and at the same time have the opportunity to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>arrow</kbd> to switch workspace (and in this case switch OS).

If I uncheck the "Catch keyboard auto" setting in settings, then I get this to work but then the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> does not work anymore inside Windows.

So, my question is:
Is there a way to, when in fullscreen Windows-guest-mode use both:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>arrow</kbd> in host Ubuntu
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> in guest Windows

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Press the "host key" first (usually <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>)

## There is a way today: Adjust your workflow

*This question has gone unanswered almost a decade. It is fair to say the solution is there, but probably not in the way the OP had hoped.*

### How desktop VMs are "supposed to" work

As of 2024, [there still isn't much *configuring* that can be done](https://superuser.com/a/323093/942694) "properly" to prevent keyboard grabbing outside of "hacking" either the hypervisor or desktop code, which may not be supported with updates.

Most solutions involve all or nothing where hotkeys are concerned:

- [via MS Windows](https://superuser.com/a/328978/942694)
- [via X window manager](https://superuser.com/a/730325/942694) (might override your original hotkey setting)
- [via VirtualBox itself](https://superuser.com/a/1118623/942694)

In fact, part of the purpose of a virtual machine is that it really does run like it has become the main system, not just another app on your desktop. One normally wants most standard desktop environment hotkeys to work inside the VM while using the VM, as much as this breaks many of our normal keyboard workflows.

***But...***

### Adapt your workflow to "using VM" mindset

By pressing and releasing the "host key" first, (usually <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>), your VirtualBox window will remain active, but your other main OS desktop hotkeys will function for your main OS desktop.

For me, I have my <kbd>Meta</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys, etc, bound on my main OS desktop environment for menus, task switching, and terminals, etc. While I use my VirtualBox window, but want to use one of my main OS desktop hotkeys, I first press <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>, then my <kbd>Meta</kbd>, <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, and other hotkeys work like I want them to.

That might address your situation.

---

**From [VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=360471)**

> VirtualBox tries to grab all keys from the host. Some operating systems and some window managers don't allow to grab certain keys or key combinations. For instance, it's not possible to grab Ctrl+Alt+Del on a Windows host as this key combination will always show the task manager. The GNOME window managers exclude other keys from grabbing.